# How to append a chunk of fixed size data to a file and make sure this chunk doesn't get fragmented on disk?

Tags: database, windows, linux, file-systems, files

So i want to understand how DBMS implementation works

To give an example :

MySQL implements each tables with its own pages, which are 16KB

so each table is a file, and is a multiple of 16KB, considering how large is it and therefore how many pages it needs

Now i read somewhere that these **pages** don't get fragmented, so my question is, HOW?

how do DBMS developers tell the operating system that "hey i just added a 16KB data (page) to this file, but make this page doesn't get fragmented"

sorry if this is a duplicate, i searched and couldn't find any related question, also lets say the O.S is windows or Linux

my point is lets say O.S stores files based on 4KB chunks, and may fragment some files when they exceed it, and the DBMS uses 16KB pages, my question is how do they implement that DBMS so that 16KB pages which get added to table files  dont get fragmented? when i append a 16KB data to a file, is it by default reserved for it and will never get fragmented? (basically how do they reserve a 16KB on the disk and make sure its not gonna get fragmented?)

if you can give an example in any language that how these type of appending is done I'm Ok, I'm not looking for a specific language just wanna know how its done

Also I'm not asking about any specific database either, all the relational databases use these pages.

ALSO **I'm taking about fragmentation inside a disk image or memory image**, not sure if these images are logical or what, so when i take the image of that database folder, or its process in memory, these pages are not fragmented, how?

Comment: Generally files are saved in chunks of 4096KB (OS-dependent however).  If the file doesn't exceed this amount, it will never be stored on multiple chunks.  [More reading here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f317b895-d46e-43e9-9636-b491c6c8908e/tips-on-preventing-file-fragmentation?forum=csharpgeneral).

Comment: @Neil I know, my point is lets say O.S stores files based on 4KB chunks, and may fragment some files when they exceed it, and the DBMS uses 16KB pages, my question is how do they implement that DBMS so that 16KB pages which get added to table files, dont get fragmented?  when i append a 16KB data to a file, is it by default reserved for it and will never get fragmented?

Comment: @OneAndOnly, this question is off topic here because it is asking about a specific implementation rather than general engineering discipline. With that said, it's a good question, and now I am very curious to the answer!

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer but based on papers that I'm reading, all of the relational databases use these pages and dont get fragmented, and im not asking about a specific database or language, just any tips on how its done. paper : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287615000584

Comment: One approach is to create a large file in advance, then defragement it (using one of the standard approaches), then write to it (e.g. starting at offset 0, as if it was blank).  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/defragmenting-files

Comment: Disk fragmentation is not user-visible, but abstracted away by the file system. Modern file systems defrag automatically in the background. Also, disk fragmentation primarily affects sequential access time on hard disks. That's not necessarily relevant for a database, especially not when using SSDs or RAID arrays. Speaking of which, SSDs often split up data internally for wear leveling. So the logical block device that the operating system sees usually has little relationship to the physical storage of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reliably talk about all filesystems and all platforms. But I have some experience in dealing with file allocation reflecting disk/volume/partition/region structure.
The most obvious way is present in WinNT NTFS disks. (I'm not entirely sure about other win FSes). It can be easily done using userspace defragmentation API.
From my point you can not only place part of file in particular positions but moreover put internal structures of NTFS (eg MFT, directory trees) in predefined order. But the latter is not 100% reliable process. This was done by me on hot running system. Take a look at Jetico BCWipe application.

Another thought: you can get full control of file allocation with your own fs driver or userspace utility but those should 
either work on unmounted device or replace system's logic entirely then.

As for other systems. I think It possible to invent some heuristic but not completely reliable algorithms for each file system type to be able to control allocation behaviour. Look at the above notice about NTFS structures.

So to summarize all this: [everything is possible]. But reliability and accompanying risks (eg design complexity) depend on the way you choose to implement such features.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. At least in the physical disk access sense.

There may be a way for particular platforms to allocate multiple contiguous chunks (e.g. ask for them all in one go), but it doesn't matter if the are or are not physically adjacent. The OS *presents* all files to you as *logically* contiguous byte sequences.

Comment: So basically whoever said that these pages don't get defragmented were LIARS!  :)

Comment: So if i take a disk image, or image of a folder content or memory image, i get these logical byte sequences right? and in that image they are not fragmented, but in the disk itself they might be, am i getting this correct? because based on these papers, these 16kb pages inside disk image and memory image dont get fragmented

Comment: one of the papers : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287615000584

Answer (score 0):

Hard Drives are pretty complex, especially now days where they can have several layers of caching in solid-state memory. Particularly active blocks in a file may never actually be written to the Hard Disk, and permanently reside in solid-state memory.

If you are optimising for sequential I/O, don't bother. The OS and hardware is already way ahead of you, any action you do take will likely slow this down. The only exception is concatenating numerous small files together, in which case you should consider this to be closer to the random I/O case.

If you are optimising for random I/O, pay attention to the Block-Size of the device. Like memory pages this is the smallest unit of Read/Write the device will perform. Design your data-structures to respect that boundary and co-locate as much relevant data within those blocks as possible, while avoiding fragmenting data across the block boundaries. In this case not using space because it is too small to store anything useful/relevant is not a sin, but a virtue.